# How to Highlight the search keyword in the autosuggestion result list React JS

Tags: reactjs

I have a search term, and based on the search term corresponding results are displayed. Trying to highlight the keyword which is search in the results list. But its giving me empty value.

this is what I tried:

```
render() {
    const { label } = this.props;
    const { searchResults, query } = this.state;
    let textHighlighter;
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <input placeholder={label} ref={input => (this.search = input)} onChange={e => this.handleInputChange(e)} />
        </form>
        {searchResults &&
          searchResults.results &&
          searchResults.results.length > 0 && (
            <ul>
              {searchResults.results.map((result, i) => {
                let searchKeywordIdx = result.indexOf(query);
                if (searchKeywordIdx > -1) {
                  textHighlighter = [
                    result.substring(0, searchKeywordIdx),
                    <strong key={i}>
                      {result.substring(searchKeywordIdx, searchKeywordIdx + query.length).substring(searchKeywordIdx + query.length)}
                    </strong>
                  ];
                }
                return <li key={result}>{textHighlighter}</li>;
              })}
            </ul>
          )}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

> Note: this.state.query = "aaa"

Example JSON:

```
searchResults.results = [“aaa”, “aaa bbb”, “aaa ccc”]
```

So I need to highlight all the `"aaa"` in the results list.

Comment: well, how did you plan to accomplish that? Your `result.substring(0, searchKeywordIdx)` returns an empty string, what was it supposed to return? Your `result.substring(searchKeywordIdx, searchKeywordIdx + query.length).substring(searchKeywordIdx + query.length)` does return an empty string as well, and what that was supposed to return in this particular example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://codepen.io/smilesaayush/pen/NzgRmW?editors=0010
fixed a little problem in your textHighlighter.

```
return (
    <div>
      {searchResults &&
        searchResults.results &&
        searchResults.results.length > 0 && (
          <ul>
            {searchResults.results.map((result, i) => {
              let searchKeywordIdx = result.indexOf(query);
              if (searchKeywordIdx > -1) {
                textHighlighter = [
                  result.substring(0, searchKeywordIdx),
                  <strong key={i}>
                    {result.substring(searchKeywordIdx, searchKeywordIdx + query.length)}
                  </strong>,
                  result.substring(searchKeywordIdx + query.length)
                ];
              }
              return <li key={result}>{textHighlighter}</li>;
            })}
          </ul>
        )}
    </div>
  );
```